# why is Copy-Item working with folders, but not with files? (\\server\file type paths)

Tags: powershell

Copy item working with folders

```
Copy-Item -Path \\sharedserver.dev.domain.com\data\testing -Destination \\sharedserver.prod.domain.com\data01
```

but not files

```
Copy-Item -Path \\sharedserver.dev.domain.com\data\testing.txt -Destination \\sharedserver.prod.domain.com\data01
```

even though i clearly see the file exists, it keeps saying the path doesnt exist...how come?

> ```
> Copy-Item : Cannot find path
> '\\sharedserver.dev.domain.com\data\testing.txt' because it does not
> exist.
> ```

Comment: Well, either the file testing.txt doesn't exists on that share or the user running that script doesn't have access to that file. It works fine on my end using shares I have access to.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I see double i in testiing

Comment: @Cataster - that was a typo ... i can't fix it, so i will delete it and add a new comment instead. thank you for catching that! [*grin*]

Comment: @Cataster - [reposted to fix significant spelling error]
your 1st line fails for me - there is no file OR dir named `..\data\testing` in that location. the 2nd line DOES work since there is a file named `..\data\testing.txt` at the source location.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thts basically the opposite of what is happening for me lol

Comment: that makes it seem like a permissions problem, then. perhaps you have permission to see the dir, but not to _directly access_ the file? i have no ide if that sort of thing is possible, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: Just a thought. What version of PowerShell are you using? Also, the error message only shows one backslash in the path it cannot find. For UNC paths this should start with two backslashes. In the code it's fine, so maybe somewhere in the rest of your code you forgot a backslash?

Comment: @Theo thts weird. I just hit edit and I can see 2 backlashes in the error message but when I save, stackoverflow parses it as 1 backlash?